# The gradle can build runnable jar made by spring boot to war file?

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I made my application using spring boot. It use embedded servlet container using tomcat library and run as application. Because I use spring boot annotation in main class for running. I used it in the local, But I have to make this application buidld war file to send the remote server where tomcat instance is listening.

First, I want to ask [this gradle plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging) I found can to it to generate the war file even if it have a main class and doesn't follow original webapp style

Second, Is there any other gradle plugin to send the war to the remote server and make tomcat redeploy the war file I sent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have the answer to your first question [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging). Spring Boot war is nothing different from traditional war so I am not sure I understand what you mean. Perhaps [Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) would help?

For your second question [gradle remote deploy war on Google](https://www.google.be/search?q=gradle+remote+deploy+war) gave me [this](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin)